# How to take out filename from link using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery.

I have got below links in my html

```
<a class="load-fragment" href="/english/india/index.aspx"><span>Overview</span></a>
<a class="load-fragment" href="/english/india/guide.aspx"><span>Guide</span></a>
```

I am trying to get out "**index**" and "**guide**" from (href="/english/india/index.aspx", href="/english/india/guide.aspx") text from above links and they will be stored in a variable for further use, there will be looping as there can be many links as given above.

Please suggest using Jquery!

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to elaborate on what "trying to get out 'index' and guide'" means. Do you want the entire `href`? Or just the name of the aspx file?

Comment: just the name from the links, in my case "index" will be taken out from href="/english/india/index.aspx and same with guide also..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
$(".load-fragment").each(function() {
   var fileName = $(this).attr("href").match(/^\/.*\/([^\/]+).aspx$/)[1];
   //store fileName where needed
});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/A3mLA/), or if say you wanted an array of them use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var files = $(".load-fragment").map(function() {
              return $(this).attr("href").match(/^\/.*\/([^\/]+).aspx$/)[1];
            }).get();​
```

Comment: This is cool, although it won't work if the file extension is not `.aspx` :P

Comment: @Jacob - Easy adjustment if needed, though given what's *usually* the case, it's probably highly unlikely that his fragment loads are anything *but* `.aspx`...looks like a vanilla ASP.Net WebForms use here.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply Nick, it worked for me, can I please ask you to look in my another question and suggest how to proceed on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952465/loading-page-fragments-on-main-page-using-jquery ..sorry for this, would appreciate if you can please suggest on that question also

Comment: Can you please also suggest how to use .load on newly created div, as I am looking to load page fragments from other pages, please the code to get dynamic div  var newDiv = $("<div>").attr("id",dynDivID); //adding div with above taken ID
            $("#column2").append(newDiv);

Comment: @Solution - Your question is very unclear, what are you trying to do, how are they being created?

Comment: I am trying to create dynamic divs on page load and then further I need to load page fragment taken from above links, can you please comment on that question so that I can modify it according to show you

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var filenames = $('.load-fragment').map(function() {
   var href =    $(this).attr('href'); 
   var lastSlash = href.lastIndexOf('/');
   var new_href = href.substring(0, lastSlash);
   return href.substring(lastSlash + 1, href.lastIndexOf('.')));
}).get();​
```

Comment: Jacod, can I please request you to please suggest on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952465/loading-page-fragments-on-main-page-using-jquery. It would be great help as I am stuck due to that

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var files = [];
$('a.load-fragment').each(function(){
    var loc = $(this).attr('href');
    loc = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    files.push(loc);
});
alert(files);
```

You can then access each of them from the files array, `files[0], files[1]`, etc.

Comment: You've left the ".aspx" on them.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Nick Craver's answer:

```
$(".load-fragment").each(function() {
   var fileName = this.href.split(/[/.]/).slice(-2,-1);
   //store fileName where needed
});
```

However, this assumes the links always have the format you show. The regex may be safer since it also is validation.

```
"/english/india/index.aspx".split(/[/.]/)
// returns: ["", "english", "india", "index", "aspx"]

["", "english", "india", "index", "aspx"].slice(-2, -1)
// returns "index"
```